# GWT showcase - navigate to a different tab programmatically

Tags: gwt, treeview

GWT showcase is available here 
http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html

It has a menu on the left. 
I am trying to navigate to a different tab on the left menu on the click of a button in the app, rather on the click of one of the menu item on the left.

Can someone suggest what i need to do. I am having a very hard time to figure this out.

What I know is the left menu is a cellTree and TreeViewModel.
Any help/suggestions here would be great

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `CellTree` instance reference? If so, you can [setKeyboardSelectedTreeNode](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTree.html#setKeyboardSelectedTreeNode(com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.TreeNode,%20int,%20boolean))

You just need to get the handle of the `TreeNode` and choose it's child index, setting the `stealFocus` parameter as `true`

---

[Here is a test case](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/master/user/test/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTreeTest.java#L270) for the `CellTree`, from the GWT itself, where you can look at examples of the selection of the `TreeNode`.